# Django Javascript and Debugging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I am trying to add a JS datepicker using jquery in my template but I can't for the life of me get it working.

My header.html (master template):

```
[...]
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-ui.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
        $( function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
              showOn: "button",
              buttonImage: "{% static 'images/calendar.gif' %}",
              buttonImageOnly: true,
              buttonText: "Select date"
            });
        } );
    </script>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
```

The template containing the script:

```
[...]
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
            {{ field.label_tag }}
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" id="datepicker">
        </div>
    </div>
[...]
```

If I make a completely bare sheet and use the script, it works find.  If I put all the code on the main header.html template, it doesn't work.  If I completely wipe my header.html and replace all the code with the script source, it works.  I don't see how my code could stop the script from working.  What am I missing here?  Also, what is a good way to troubleshoot when the development server is remote?

Comment: Good way to debug is to open chrome dev tools and look for errors in the console.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty standard.  I do that already but in this case it doesn't provide me any fruitful answers for this problem :(

Comment: Need to start fiddling with it then. View the page source to make sure your code is all there, add `console.log($( "#datepicker"))` and see if it could find that div.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what is the error message or what happens? Also check the console for errors and my HTML debugging answer below.

Comment: My site works, the input box shows up, but no JavaScript and no calendar image to click on.  https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger.   I'll give what you've described a try but chrome's inspect already does that (flags errors).  This far I haven't found any syntax errors.  It's all pretty standard stuff.  Troubleshooting Django is what is a pain when it doesn't throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging HTML:

Open the page in *Firefox* (not another browser) and view source (ctrl-u on Linux or Windows, command-u on Mac). Firefox will highlight errors in HTML when viewing source.

To see errors, you have to use Firefox and look at the source via the "view source" option -- don't use the browser console/inspector, because the inspector shows the live DOM, not the HTML source code.

If you install html tidy, then you could save the source of the page and run `tidy my-file.html` to scan it for syntax errors. It will show the errors like this:

[image]

Comment: This is showing the same things I was seeing with view source on chrome.  No errors are highlighted.  I did find a broken link to jquery.js by clicking through all my links in the <head> tags, but fixing it didn't fix my problem.  I compared the sources on the working plain page and the broken page and don't see any differences.

Comment: Starting to wonder if I should just force HTML5 and use <input type="date" />  Seems it populates automatically with a datepicker.  Feeling like it's a bad idea, but hey..  We're in the industry of technology :P

Comment: Yup, it is a bad idea.  Seems thats a Chrome thing.  Firefox doesn't have a datepicker built in, or it just doesn't recognize that HTML5 element type yet.

Comment: [link](http://blog.automationintegrity.net/music/album/add/)  -  My code  [link](http://php.automationintegrity.net/test.html)  -  Working barebones code.  Can you see anything?

Comment: View source and look closely. Your scripts aren't being loaded on the page: `<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-ui.js"></script>`. There is an error in the browser console that `$` is not defined.

Comment: You're running your script in the `<head>` before jQuery is loaded at the bottom of the page. So it can't find jQuery.

Comment: If you could, take another look.  I was messing around with it earlier today and what you saw wasn't where I left off.

Comment: I moved everything from the bottom to the head and it worked, above the query script I already had in place.  I wonder which part makes this work.  Bootstrap puts everything at the bottom in their example code.

Comment: Thanks for leading me to the answer good sir.  I'll post what I find is causing the problem later when I have time.  I suspect it's the window.jQuery statement.  First time using java purposefully and regretting it!  :P. On to the next battle - Django form manipulation and control.

Comment: It's better to put your scripts at the bottom. It should still work if you move all of them to the bottom. The other version probably didn't work, because it wasn't finding jQuery. The rest of the code looked okay.

Comment: If I move all the scripts to the bottom, does that include the functions?  I tried it earlier and it didn't work, but I think I moved the function to the form template.

Comment: All of the `<script>` elements, including the one that contains your JS code. Keep them in the same order at the bottom. Put them right above the `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add a debugger / breakpoint in your code as shown in the sample below. This will stop the page (in your browser) at the debugger point. From there, you can use it as a regular debugger as is the case with most IDE's. This is what I use for debugging JavaScript with Django template rendering / backend.

**Make sure to have your developer window on in your browser. (Right click and inspect)**

```
let button = document.createElement('a');
button.classList = this.hasButton === 'true' ? 'btn btn-primary btn-sm disabled' : 'btn btn-primary btn-sm disabled d-none';
button.textContent = 'Button';
debugger; // This will stop the browser at this line
card.append(button)
```